# How to "refresh" a single page application

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, single-page-application

Suppose I have a single page application that makes AJAX requests to `http://www.somesite.com/resources?lang=en`.

Now, let's say that my application has a special variable for the request's languages, that is, if the variable's value is `en`, then the AJAX request will send a query param `lang=en`.

For now, the two possible values are `en` and `es`.

This variable's value can be changed dynamically by the user (clicking a button).

So, if we are using the application with `language = en`, then the application will send the `lang=en` query parameter. If the user changes the language to `es`, then I want the application to ***resend*** all the AJAX requests but now with `lang=es` query parameter.

It would be like refreshing the website, but asynchronously via AJAX requests.

I have been thinking this yesterday and I can't find a way to handle this logic in an AngularJS application.

I'm not an expert in AngularJS, but I understand the concepts of modules, directives, services and controllers.

What would be the best approach to handle this scenario? That is, I would like to avoid having to call each AJAX request manually, I'd rather create an automatic way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any AngularJS plugins?
First that comes to mind is [Angular translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/)

Comment: I'm using `Angular Translate` too. But there are resources that are returned from the server, and those resources need translation. We decided to do that translation on server-side via query parameters

Answer (score 0):

Best way to concate the ajax url with lang parameter and request again.

So you will get all new data base on lang parameter, won't forget to handle cache before requesting the ajax call.

Comment: I was looking for a way to handle the resending of **all** my ajax requests on the application. More like a service, where I would execute it as `myService.refreshPage(lang)`

Comment: yes create a method refreshPage() and all all the requests there.

Comment: As I stated on the question, I don't want to send the request manually, I would like my application to send them all without having to call them manually on code, so it's flexible for me to add or remove AJAX calls on other sections of my application. More like my service identifying the AJAX calls on my website, and resending them all